# Unittesting Python code which uses subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, git, unit-testing

I have a Python project in which I read external files, process them, and write the results to a new file. The input files can either be read directly, or extracted from a git repository using `git show`. The function to call `git show` and return stdout looks like this:

```
def git_show(fname, rev):
    '''Runs git show and returns stdout'''
    process = subprocess.Popen(['git', 'show', '{}:{}'.format(rev, fname)],
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    ret_code = process.wait()
    if ret_code:
        raise Exception(stderr)
    return stdout
```

I have unittests which test the whole processing part of the program, i.e., everything apart from reading and writing the files. However, I have stumbled upon (and fixed) issues regarding the encoding of the returned string from `git_show()`, depending Python version, and quite possibly OS and the actual file to read.

I would like to set up a unittest for `git_show()` so I can make sure the whole application works, from input to output. However, as far as I know, this is not possible without having an actual git repository to test on. The whole package is version managed with git, and I expect that if I have a git repository inside a git repository that might lead to problems on its own, and a voice in my head tells me that might not be the best solution anyway.

How can one best achieve unittesting code which gets input from `git show` (and in general, the command line / `Popen.communicate()`)?

Answer (score 5):

So the way I do this is with [pytest](https://pytest.org)

**Example:** (*contrived*)

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


def test():
    p = Popen(["echo", "Hello World!"], stdout=PIPE)
    stdout, _ = p.communicate()

    assert stdout == b"Hello World!\n"
```

**Output:**

```
$ py.test -x -s test_subprocess.py 
======================================= test session starts ========================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.9 -- py-1.4.28 -- pytest-2.7.1
rootdir: /home/prologic/work/circuits, inifile: 
plugins: cov
collected 1 items 

test_subprocess.py .

===================================== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds =====================================
```

---

Or using the standard library [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html):

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from unittest import main, TestCase


from subprocess import Popen, PIPE


class TestProcess(TestCase):

    def test(self):
        p = Popen(["echo", "Hello World!"], stdout=PIPE)
        stdout, _ = p.communicate()

        self.assertEquals(stdout, b"Hello World!\n")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
$ python test_subprocess.py 
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: 1. Does this require ``py.test`` or is ``unittest`` sufficient? 2. You're boomeranging a string originating from inside the python file. Are there important encoding implications arising from this, or will ``stdout.read()`` in your example definitely return the exact same string/encoding as if you're calling ``git show`` on a file with the same string, no matter how the file is saved?

Comment: No; pytest is not required; you *can* use unittest. You will get bytes in Python 3.x and str in Python 2.x (*equivalent to bytes*); ``stdout`` will contain the output of ``git show``

Comment: Thanks, will test it and see. Is this true for Win/Mac/Linux, and should ``echo`` work on all three?

Comment: I can't *vouch* for Windows; but Linux and Mac sure.

Comment: When I try this (with ``shell=True`` which is the only way to access ``echo`` on Windows), ``stdout`` only contains the first line of the input string. Is there any way to make this work with multiline strings?

Comment: ``echo -e`` to interpreter ``\n`` chars int eh string? -- Sorry I have no idea wrt Windows systems

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you want (one of combination of) **different kinds of tests**.

**Unit tests**

Test a small part of your code, within your code.

1. mock out `subprocess.Popen`
2. return static values in `stdout, stderr`
3. check that processing is correct

Sample code is pretty small, you can only test that `stdout` is really returned and that upon non-zero `wait()` an exception is raised.

**Something in between**

Test vectors, that is given set input, set output should be produced

1. mock out git, instead use `cat vector1.txt` encoded in specific way
2. test result

**Integration tests**

Test how your code connects to external entities, in this case `git`. Such tests protects you from accidentally changing the expectation of the internal system. That is it "freezes" the API.

1. create a tarball with a small git repository
2. optionally pack git binary into same tarball
3. unpack the tarball
4. run git command
5. compare output to expected